# Highlight value on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight text inside `.category-value` class on hover over `div` with class `month-hover` to apply `#197ABF` color. ie., **"Jan"** text should be of color `#197ABF` on hover over div.

I tried applying the below CSS,but not working(as its highlighting only on mouse hover over `Jan` or `Feb`).

```
.month-hover>.category-title:hover{
    color:#197ABF;
}
```

Plunker link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hrJyoo?p=preview)

Comment: Solved by adding `.month-hover:hover .category-title {
    color: #197ABF;
} `   Plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/eXJewR?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the dot (`.`) before your `category-title` class:

```
.month-hover > .category-title:hover {
    color: #197ABF;
}
```

Comment: This is changing on hover of Jan.But I want to change color on hover of the div along with blue border

Comment: @forgottofly So, why is that not in your question?

Comment: @Robby.Guess my question confused users.Edited my question..

Answer (score 1):

This works if, parent class and then child class. This will change the color of text when hovered. (Missed the `.`)

```
.month-hover .category-title:hover{
    color:#197ABF;
}
```

To change the color of text when div hover is simple,

**Full code:**

```css
.margin-set{
  margin:35px;
}
.category-title{
  font-size:15px;
}
.category-value{
  font-size:45px;
  color:#197ABF;
}

.month-hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid transparent 2px;
}
.month-hover:hover {
    border-color: #197ABF;
    color:#197ABF;
}
/*.month-hover>.category-title:hover{
    color:#197ABF;
}
.month-hover >.category-title:hover{
    color:#197ABF;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-5-columns.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container margin-set">
      <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-md-6 month-hover">
        <div class="col-sm-5th-2 category-title">Jan</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5th-3  category-value">2017</div>
      </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6 month-hover">
        <div class="col-sm-5th-2 category-title">Feb</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5th-3  category-value">2017</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Just added color to the on hover of the div.

**Result:**
[image]

*(Blue arrow is where the mouse is at)*

Comment: This is changing on hover of Jan.But I want to change color on hover of the div along with blue border

Comment: @forgottofly edited, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
.month-hover .category-title:hover{
    color:#197ABF;
}
```